# how to zoom in and zoom out a QGraphicsWidget by Button?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have an example of `QGraphicsWidget`. i want to added a tow button , a button for Zoom In , and a button for the Zoom out . the code :

```
#include "myGraphicsWidget.h"
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;

    myGraphicsWidget* graphicsWidget = new myGraphicsWidget("This is My Custom\n QGraphicsWidget!!");

    QGraphicsView view(&scene);        
    scene.addItem(graphicsWidget);

    view.showFullScreen();

    return app.exec

();

}
```

please write to me a function (slot) for Zoom .

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the wheelEvent or create a button that handle the scale of the QGraphicsView:

```
void myGraphicsWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    qreal zoomFactor = 1.15;
    if (event->delta() > 0 && zoomLevel < 20) {
        // Zoom In
        scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
    } else if (event->delta() < 0 && zoomLevel > 0) {
        // Zooming out
        scale(1.0 / zoomFactor, 1.0 / zoomFactor);
    }
    scrollViewTo(event->pos());
}
```

for a Slot, that would be the same - but you would need to separate the code for zoomIn and zoomOut.